# Yii2 mPDF my footer only show on the last page

Tags: php, mpdf

I want to set a footer on my PDF page using mPDF library but my footer only shows on the last page.
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vAS0.png)
as you can see the previous page doesn't show footer but the second (last page) does.

I've tried putting footer before content like this

```
$this->SetFooter($footer);
$stylesheet = file_get_contents(Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . '/web/css/bootstrap3.7.min.css');
$stylesheet .= $css;
$this->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$this->WriteHTML($content, 2);
```

or this

```
$this->SetFooter($footer);
$this->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$this->WriteHTML($content, 2);
```

but none of them works.
here is my component.

```
public function genPdf($content, $css = '', $footer = [], $additionals = [], $watermark = "")
  {

    $stylesheet = file_get_contents(Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . '/web/css/bootstrap3.7.min.css');
    $stylesheet .= $css;
    $this->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
    $this->WriteHTML($content, 2);


    if ($footer) {
      $this->SetFooter($footer);
    }

    if ($watermark) {
      $this->WriteHTML('<watermarktext content="' . $watermark . '" alpha="0.3" />');
    }

    if (count($additionals)) {
      $basePath = Yii::getAlias('@webroot');
      $index = 0;

      foreach ($additionals as $doc) {
        // $this->SetImportUse();
        if ($doc['kind'] === 'pdf') {
          continue;
          $fileName = $basePath . '/tmp/file' . $index . '.pdf';
          file_put_contents($fileName, fopen($doc['uri'], 'r'));
          if (file_exists($fileName)) {
            $pagecount = $this->setSourceFile($fileName);

            if ($pagecount) {
              $tplId = $this->importPage($pagecount);
              $this->AddPage();
              $this->useTemplate($tplId);
              $this->useTemplate($tplId, 50, 50, 100, 100);
              $this->WriteHTML('<watermarktext content="' . $doc['name'] . '" alpha="0.3" />');
            }
          }
        } else if ($doc['kind'] === 'jpg') {
          $fileName = $basePath . '/tmp/file' . $index . '.jpg';
          file_put_contents($fileName, fopen($doc['uri'], 'r'));
          if (file_exists($fileName)) {
            $this->AddPage();
            $this->Image($fileName, 0, 0, 210, 297, 'jpg', '', true, false);
            $this->WriteHTML('<watermarktext content="' . $doc['name'] . '" alpha="0.3" />');
          }
        }

        $index++;
      }
    }

    if (!empty($this->filename)) {
      $this->Output($this->filename, 'I');
    } else {
      $this->Output();
    }
  }
```

and this is my controller

```
private function footer()
  {
    $dtime = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", date('Y-m-d'));
    $timestamp = $dtime->getTimestamp();
    $footer = array(
      'odd' => array(
        'L' => array(
          'content' => 'create by: ABC'. ' (' .  Yii::$app->date->date($timestamp) . ')',
          'font-size' => 10,
          'font-family' => 'garuda',
        ),
        'R' => array(
          'content' => "{PAGENO}/{nb}",
          'font-size' => 11,
          'font-family' => 'garuda',
        ),
        'line' => 1,
      ),
      'even' => array(
        'L' => array(
          'content' => 'create by: ABC'. ' (' .  Yii::$app->date->date($timestamp) . ')',
          'font-size' => 10,
          'font-family' => 'garuda',
        ),
        'R' => array(
          'content' => "{PAGENO}/{nb}",
          'font-size' => 11,
          'font-family' => 'garuda',
        ),
        'line' => 1,
      ),
    );

    return $footer;
  }

  private function outputPDF($fileName, $content, $cssFilePath, $overrideConfig = [], $additionals = [], $watermark = "")
  {

    $mpdf = new NgMpdf('utf-8', 'A4', 12, 'thsarabunnew', $left = 18, $right = 13, $top = 8, $bottom = 8, $mgh = 5, $mgf = 2, 'P');

    $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
    $mpdf->filename = $fileName . ".pdf";
    $mpdf->title = $fileName;

    $customCssContent = $this->getBasePdfCss();
    if (!empty($cssFilePath)) {
      $customCssContent .= file_get_contents($cssFilePath);
    }


    $mpdf->genPdf($content, $customCssContent, $this->footer(), $additionals, $watermark);
  }
```